# Ubb forum error Unable to connect to the database!

Tags: php, mysql

I have recently migrated my ubb forum website to a new web hosting server, I have placed the files on new server and I think directory structure is right and also set up the database through phpmyadmin, and changed config file accordingly but still I am getting this error

UBB Message We encountered a problem. The reason reported was

```
Script:

Line#:

SQL Error:

SQL Error #:

Query: Unable to connect to the database!
```

I think all the info that i have filled in config file here:

```
'DATABASE_SERVER' => 'db.aa.0000000.hostedresource.com',
'DATABASE_USER' => 'abcd',
'DATABASE_PASSWORD' => 'cccc',
'DATABASE_NAME' => 'ssddd',
```

is correct because I tried to connect to db through another script and it did work and retrieved the data so I am totally confused what I am doing wrong.

Comment: the reason reported was?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that this is the correct configuration data?  Did you perhaps copy it into your config file wrong?  That would seem to be the most likely source of errors (e.g. the script that worked had similar, but slightly different values which were actually correct and on first blush look like the ones in your config file).